# What's the next step in creating a temp converter?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, converters, temp

This is my very first time trying to create a simple program by using JS and I am a beginner, so please bear with me. I am here because I feel like I have all these pieces of code but I can't understand how to link them together. I have two functions inside the form that work on their own but I clearly need to link them to the result statement inside the if statement and I am not sure how to do that. Also, I am sure this is poorly written code but for now I am just focussing on having a working program.  This is the JS code I have so far (HTML after that):

```
    // grab elements & store in variable
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const selectCelsius = document.getElementById("celsius")
const selectFahrenheit = document.getElementById("fahrenheit")
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    
    const fahrenheit = (c) => {
   
        let f = (c * 9/5) + 32
        
        return f
    
    }

    const celsius = (f) => {

        let c = ((f - 32) * 5) - 9
    
        return c
    }

if (selectCelsius === "Celsius" && submit.innerHTML === "CONVERT") {
   return result.innerHTML = "Your result is " + userInput(fahrenheit)
} 
if (selectFahrenheit === "Fahrenheit" && submit.innerHTML === "CONVERT") {
    return result.innerHTML = "Your result is " + userInput(celsius)
}

})
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="sub-wrapper">
            <div class="weather">
                <img src="./img/weather.png" alt="weather">
                
                    <h1>temperature converter</h1>
                
            </div>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="number" id="userInput" name="temperature" placeholder="temperature">
                    <select name="temperature" id="temperature">
                        <option value="celsius" id="celsius">Celsius</option>
                        <option value="fahrenheit" id="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                    </select>
               
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="CONVERT"></input>
                
            </form>
            <p id="result"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. First of all, you are accessing the values of user-input at the time of the application-load, hence when the user makes any changes in the input box and submits, the value entered by the user doesn't reach javascript.
2. The logical check applied inside the submit event's callback function are not correct. You need to access the value of the `select` element which has id `temperature`.
3. The function invocation for calculating the conversion was also wrong in your case. Function invocation follows `<function-name>(<argument>)` pattern. Hence it should be `fahrenheit(userInput)` instead of `userInput(fahrenheit)`. and similarly `celsius(userInput)`

Following changes in the `js` code should give you the expected outcome.

```
// grab elements & store in variable
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

const result = document.getElementById("result");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  const selectTemperature = document.getElementById("temperature").value;

  const fahrenheit = c => {
    let f = (c * 9) / 5 + 32;
    return f;
  };

  const celsius = f => {
    let c = (f - 32) * 5 - 9;
    return c;
  };

  if (selectTemperature === "celsius") {
    result.innerHTML = "Your result is " + fahrenheit(userInput);
  }

  if (selectTemperature === "fahrenheit") {
    result.innerHTML = "Your result is " + celsius(userInput);
  }
})
```

Here is a link to my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kruqd1

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your explanation. I'm actually quite glad I was at least going in the right direction. Your n1 point helped me understanding why I'd need to grab the value input only inside the function and not before I create it. I hadn't realised the issue with the selectTemperature variable. I have a few questions though. Why did you move the preventDefault function at the end of the eventListener function? Why did you console.log the userInput value in the celsius statement only? Thanks a lot for the help, I banged my head against the wall the whole day yesterday about this!!

Comment: I moved the e.preventDefault() to the end by mistake. It should be on top.
And I had added the `console.log` statements to debug while I was looking for issues in your code. I will update it in my answer.

Comment: Please accept the answer if my response solves your problem. Thanks!